# How broad was the rejection of the Ethiopia-Somaliland deal in the Somaliland parliament?

Tags: parliament, foreign-policy, ethiopia, somaliland, foreign-bases

AA has a [piece](https://www.aa.com.tr/en/africa/somaliland-lawmakers-shoot-down-red-sea-access-deal-with-ethiopia/3137345) (from Feb) that says that legislators in the Somaliland parliament rejected the deal with Ethiopia (roughly a naval base for recognition):

> Lawmakers in Somalia's breakaway region of Somaliland have rejected a maritime access deal with Ethiopia.
>
> In a joint statement late on Tuesday, members of both houses of Somaliland's parliament, mainly from the coastal Awdal and Salal provinces, said the Red Sea access deal was "illegal" and aims to "harm the unity of the people of Somaliland." [...]
>
> The statement pointed to "conflicting statements" from leaders of Somaliland and Ethiopia on the deal [...]

However, the AA piece doesn't exactly say how broad this rejection was. So, how many Somaliland legislators (out of the total) have publicly opposed that deal?